# what does the mapping in this exercise for uniform convergence mean

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces.
Show: If $A_n(t)\in L(X,Y)$ converges strongly and uniformly for $t\in [0,1]$ and if $x\in C^1([0,1],X)$, then $A_n(t)x(t)$ converges uniformly for $t\in [0,1]$.

I am having trouble with this exercise as it doesn't even make sense to me. If $A_n$ are maps from $X\to Y$, what does $A_n(t)$ even mean? And since $A_n$ maps so an element of $Y$ and $x(t)$ to an element of $X$, what does $A_n(t)x(t)$ even mean?

Can anyone help me understand this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context is the following: *for a fixed $t$*, $A_n(t)$ is an element of $L(X,Y)$. For a fixed $t$, $x(t)$ belongs to $X$, hence $A(t)[x(t)]$ makes sense.

Comment: oh, so basically we have a map that is only implicitly mentioned that maps $[0,1]\to L(X,Y), t\mapsto A_n(t)$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$